Proving fact about reduction function and natural addition
I have a recursive function that produces a tuple of Nat which represents a sort of difference between two Nats
def reduce : Nat → Nat → Nat × Nat
  | .succ n1, .succ n2 => reduce n1 n2
  | 0, .succ n2 => (0, n2.succ)
  | .succ n1, 0 => (n1.succ, 0)
  | 0, 0 => (0, 0)

#eval reduce 5 2 -- (3, 0)
#eval reduce 10 8 -- (2, 0)
#eval reduce 8 10 -- (0, 2)

I now want to prove a fact that relates the two to a sort of swapped addition. However the starting point with a simpler case when one side is zero is difficult to prove enough.
(I think) I know:

Want to use induction to reduce the first case
Induction on a doesn't produce good results

So far I have this. But am stuck at the last step
theorem reduce.right_zero (n: Nat) : reduce n 0 = (n, 0) := reduce.of_zero n _ (Or.inr rfl)

/-
  example reduce 3 2 = (1, 0). Therefore 1 + 2 = 3
-/
theorem reduce.left_addition (a b c: Nat): (a, 0) = (reduce b c) → a + c = b := by
  intro h1
  induction c generalizing a with
  | zero => {
    rw [reduce.right_zero] at h1;
    have h2 := (Prod.ext_iff.mp h1).right; simp at h2;
    have h3 := (Prod.ext_iff.mp h1).left; simp at h3;
    rw [h3];
    exact (Nat.add_zero _)
  }
  | succ c ih => {
    specialize ih a.succ
    rw [Nat.succ_add, ←Nat.add_succ, Nat.succ_eq_add_one c] at ih
    apply ih
    -- Stuck here
    sorry
  }

I don't really understand this reduce function (I don't even if that is the correct name) and made it up to implement integer addition.
Any guidance on the next steps?

You could think of reduce as Nat subtraction with remainder: e.g. 5-2 = 3 with a remainder of 0, while 8-10 = 0 with a remainder of 2.  Equivalently, the result is a (normalized) integer in a Nat*Nat encoding.  --  I have been able to prove your theorem in Coq by initially induction on a generalizing on all others: but then among other things I have had to use inversion (equality of subterms from equality of terms), and I do not know how that goes in Lean...

@JulioDiEgidio I see. I don't know Coq but I think inversion is a sort of congr_arg in Lean (which I haven't proved for a fixed LHS of reduce but should be true). Would be great if you could post your proof in Coq and I can have a look at the structure!

Sorry, it was by induction on b...  Anyway, I have posted an answer with the Coq code: I hope that helps and feel free to ask for clarifications if needed.

It's not that hard to just prove the general statement that you are after. One improvement worth making, already suggested by Julio Di Egidio, is in the definition of reduce to have three cases instead of four. This way reduce 0 b computes for arbitrary b.
def reduce : Nat → Nat → Nat × Nat
  | 0, b => (0, b)
  | .succ a, 0 => (.succ a, 0)
  | .succ a, .succ b => reduce a b

def reduce_add : ∀ (a b : Nat), a + (reduce a b).snd = b + (reduce a b).fst := by
  intro a
  induction a
  case zero => simp [reduce]
  case succ a ih =>
    intro b
    cases b
    case zero => simp [reduce]
    case succ b =>
      simp [reduce]
      rw [add_comm a 1, add_assoc 1 a, ih b]
      rw [← add_assoc 1 b, add_comm b 1]

If you are using mathlib and do import Mathlib.Tactic the last two lines of rewrites can be replaced with linarith [ih b].

Thanks! Hadn't appreciated there was a simpler definition for reduce. I guess the order of patterns has an effect. For those interested here is the code I used in the body to get it to work in the first definition of the question:
  have h2 : a = (reduce₂ b c).fst := (Prod.ext_iff.mp h1).left
  rw [h2, Nat.add_comm, ←reduce_add]
  conv => rhs; rw [←Nat.add_zero b];
  rw [Nat.add_left_cancel_iff]
  exact (Prod.ext_iff.mp h1).right.symm


You could think of reduce as Nat subtraction with remainder: e.g. 5-2 = 3 with a remainder of 0, while 8-10 = 0 with a remainder of 2. Equivalently, the result is a normalized (whence maybe the "reduce") integer in a Nat*Nat encoding.
I have been able to prove your theorem in Coq by initially induction on a [EDIT: sorry, by induction on your b actually] with all others general: but then among other things I have had to use inversion (equality of subterms from equality of terms), and I do not know how that goes in Lean.
Anyway, as per your kind request, here is the proof in Coq for reference.  Notice that I have slightly simplified the definition of reduce, which makes using it slightly simpler.  Indeed, the proof of the theorem reflects the structure of the definition pretty closely:
Fixpoint reduce (x y : nat) : nat * nat :=
  match x, y with
  | 0   , _    => (0, y)
  | _   , 0    => (x, 0)
  | S x', S y' => reduce x' y'
  end.

Check eq_refl : reduce  5  2 = (3, 0).
Check eq_refl : reduce 10  8 = (2, 0).
Check eq_refl : reduce  8 10 = (0, 2).

Lemma reduce_left_add : forall x y d,
  reduce x y = (d, 0) -> d + y = x.
Proof.
  induction x as [|x' Ix'].
  all: intros y d H.
  - (* H : reduce 0 y = (d, 0) *)
    cbn in H.
    inversion H; subst.
    reflexivity.
  - destruct y as [|y'].
    + (* H : reduce (S x') 0 = (d, 0) *)
      cbn in H.
      inversion H; subst.
      rewrite <- plus_n_O.
      reflexivity.
    + (* H : reduce (S x') (S y') = (d, 0) *)
      cbn in H.
      apply Ix' in H; subst.
      rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.
      reflexivity.
Qed.

If you do not have Coq installed, here is a playground: https://jscoq.github.io/wa/
